# oracle trigger for user restriction based on terminal

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to restrict Oracle users from logging into database except for a couple of terminal. I have written below trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_IP_RESTRICT
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE

DECLARE
  V_USER  VARCHAR2(30);
  V_GRP   VARCHAR2(50);   
BEGIN

  SELECT USER INTO V_USER FROM DUAL;

  V_GRP := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL');

  IF V_USER IN ('<list of users>') THEN
    IF V_GRP NOT IN ('<list of terminals>') THEN

      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
                              'Access Denied by DBA TEAM : ' || V_GRP ||
                              ' on ' || V_USER || ' from ' ||
                              SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));

    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

---

Even though it's working fine and going in exception part, which should happen technically. But at the same time, it is allowing the connection instead of showing the error message to the user.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Such trigger works only for non-DBA users, none precisely users which do not have `adminster database trigger` privilege.

Otherwise you may block your entire database.

Comment: There is a workaround to this limitation, see my answer.  You're right that this can block your entire database, which is not a fun situation.

Comment: So what is the solution in this case? Let me mention my requirement again.     I want to restrict access of my colleagues on a database when they try to log in from their personal desktops. So I am using terminal ids.

Comment: My first idea would be to use a firewall.  I guess that is the default solution.

Comment: That includes the network team. There must be some smart way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g1662184):

> If the system trigger is a DATABASE LOGON trigger and the user has
>   ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER privilege, then the user is able to log on
>   successfully even if the trigger raises an exception. For SCHEMA LOGON
>   triggers, if the user logging on is the trigger owner or has ALTER ANY
>   TRIGGER privileges then logon is permitted. Only the trigger action is
>   rolled back and an error is logged in the trace files and alert log.

You can workaround this restriction by raising an ORA-600 error that will break the entire session.  The error message won't be helpful to the user but it at least stops them.

The sample code below will stop absolutely everyone from connecting to the database, even SYSDBA.  **Be very careful running this.**  Make sure you have another session connected to the database and run `drop trigger TRG_IP_RESTRICT;` when you are done testing it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_IP_RESTRICT
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE

DECLARE
  V_USER  VARCHAR2(30);
  V_GRP   VARCHAR2(50);   

  --Only an ORA-600 error can stop logons for users with either
  --"ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER" or "ALTER ANY TRIGGER".
  --The ORA-600 also generates an alert log entry and may warn an admin.
  internal_exception exception;
  pragma exception_init( internal_exception, -600 );

BEGIN

  SELECT USER INTO V_USER FROM DUAL;

  V_GRP := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL');

  IF V_USER IN ('<list of users>') THEN
    IF V_GRP NOT IN ('<list of terminals>') THEN


      raise internal_exception;

--      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
--                              'Access Denied by DBA TEAM : ' || V_GRP ||
--                              ' on ' || V_USER || ' from ' ||
--                              SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'));

    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

With that trigger in place, even DBA users will get this error message when they connect:

```
ERROR:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [600], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
[], [], [], []
ORA-06512: at line 21
```

Comment: What do you think? Is it a proper solution? Even no one will be able to login including Sys user. Isn't it?

Comment: I put back the "IF" conditions - I only commented them out because that might be useful for testing.  You have full control over access and you can make an exception for a user like SYS with another condition.

Comment: No, it didn't work for me. Just to mention that I created the trigger from sys user. And then tried to login with another user which has DBA privilege and login was successful.

Comment: Try (temporarily) removing all the IF conditions.  I've used this trick on several versions and platforms, there should be a way to make it work.

Comment: I am not sure but as far as I remember there are tools (e.g. Sql developer) where you can set USERENV with arbitrary values. In such case it would be trivial to bypass the trigger.

Comment: Nope. No luck even after removing all if conditions. Now it's becoming mystery.